# invalid number error for date difference

Tags: oracle

I want calculate difference in two dates and round that to 4 decimal.
But following query gives me error as invalid number.
What is wrong

```
SELECT ROUND((TO_DATE(to_char('26-02-2016 12:44:00','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI') - TO_DATE(to_char('26/02/2016 12:38','DD/MM/YY HH24:MI'),'DD/MM/YY HH24:MI')), 4) 
from dual;
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call `to_char` on a string (just as you shouldn't call `to_date` on a date).  Just call `to_date` to convert the string into a date.  Your format masks also need to match the string-- you're using 4 digit years so use `YYYY` in the format mask and you either want to remove the seconds from the first string or add seconds to your format mask.

```
SELECT ROUND( to_date( '26-02-2016 12:44','DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI') -
                to_date( '26/02/2016 12:38','DD/MM/YYYY HH24:MI'),
              4 )
  FROM dual
```